# db_datareader, db_datawriter and db_owner permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions

First of all, sry because I am not a DBA and I'm not familiar with all the permissions.

My question is, if I give a user `db_owner` permissions on one database. Do I need to give also `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` permissions to have full control? I think `db_owner` is sufficient to execute all kind of queries on the database? (create, delete, alter, select and all other stuff).

So, in short: If I choose `db_owner`, then `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter` are automatically included. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Database-Level Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121%28v=sql.120%29.aspx):

> Members of the db_owner fixed database role can perform all configuration and maintenance activities on the database, and can also drop the database.

A member of this Database level role can do whatever he wants on the database. This also include SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE data.

You still have to make sure that you are not giving too much rights to a user when you make him a menber of db_owner...

You can connect with this user on your database and run this query to see effective Database level permissions using [sys.fn_my_permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms176097%28v=sql.120%29.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_my_permissions(null, 'database')
--WHERE permission_name IN ('SELECT', 'UPDATE', 'DELETE', 'INSERT')
ORDER BY permission_name
```

Output with only db_owner includes following rows:

```
entity_name subentity_name  permission_name
...         ...             ...
database                    DELETE
database                    INSERT
database                    SELECT
database                    UPDATE
...         ...             ...
```

Comment: These permissions are for a service account and db_owner is a prerequisite. But sometimes I see that for a SQL Login all three permissions are selected (db_datareader, db_datawriter and db_owner), actually when selecting db_owner, then db_datareader and db_datawriter should be grayed out because it's unnecessary to select those also

Comment: at the database level, db_owner is the highest you can go although you can still check any lower level roles such as db_datareader or over roles with rights already included in db_owner.

Answer (score 5):

You **dont** need to to give db_datareader and db_datawriter permission if you have given db_owner permission. As per BOL

> db_owner:
>
> Members of the db_owner fixed database role can perform all
>   configuration and maintenance activities on the database, and can also
>   drop the database.

Even if you check the checkboxes for respective roles it won't have any affect